# How to fix a cmdline excute error? Used python to crawl a web page

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

I was trying to crawl a webpage, part of the code is shown below. But I got the errors. Thanks a lot for your help.
I was trying to crawl a webpage, part of the code is shown below. But I got the errors. Thanks a lot for your help.

```html
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy import cmdline
import re
import pandas as pd
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

# browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/zhen/Downloads/chromedriver')#声明浏览器对象

class GofundSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'gofund'
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    cmdline.execute('scrapy crawl gofund'.split())
```

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gofund.py", line 111, in <module>
    cmdline.execute('scrapy crawl gofund'.split())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 113, in execute
    settings = get_project_settings()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/utils/project.py", line 69, in get_project_settings
    settings.setmodule(settings_module_path, priority='project')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/settings/__init__.py", line 287, in setmodule
    module = import_module(module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gofundme'
```

Comment: What have you done to try and fix the `No module named 'gofundme'` error?

Comment: Please remove the duplicate words

Answer (score 1):

A better way to run spider as a script

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class GofundSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your spider Here
    ...

process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
    #all your settings here
})

process.crawl(GofundSpider)
process.start()
```